# Listening for events in another component and waiting for reply

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to add a JPanel to my GUI, which will have some buttons say, b1, b2, b3. This JPanel will be added dynamically, while the application is already running, on the press of a button, say b. When I display the JPanel, the button b will not work until one of the buttons b1, b2, b3 is pressed.

I created the JPanel class which contains the buttons b1, b2, b3 and added the event handlers and inside the mouse event handler for the button b, I instantiated the object of the jPanel. So, the JPanel is getting displayed, but the button b is not waiting for a response from b1, b2 & b3.

The rest of the button b's event code will depend on which choice is made between b1,b2 and b3. So it will pause that that line of the code until a choice is made.

How can I stop the button b, until one of the buttons are selected?

Here is an MCVE...

1) Main class...

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

2) Frame class...

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        super.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b = new JButton("Click Me!!");
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                Frame.super.add(panel);

                // After this I have more handling code, which depends on which button was chosen.
                // But I cant stop the execution at this point and make it wait for a choice.

                Frame.super.revalidate();
            }
        });
        super.add(b);
        super.validate();
    }
}
```

3) Panel class...

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    public Panel() {
        super.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        super.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                // return button ??
                // return the name of the button to the event handler of the button b in the JFrame for further execution.
            }
        };

        JButton b1 = new JButton("option 1");
        b1.addMouseListener(listener);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("option 2");
        b2.addMouseListener(listener);
        JButton b3 = new JButton("option 3");
        b3.addMouseListener(listener);

        super.add(b1);
        super.add(b2);
        super.add(b3);
    }
}
```

The parts where I want to add some code are commented and the functionality I want to add is explained.

Comment: It would certainly be a lot easier for me to provide you an answer if you would post your code. A [mcve] is preferred.

Comment: @Abra I added some code, which explains the problem. This is just dummy code, actual application is much larger.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tip, I added a complete MCVE this time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of displaying a dialog on top of a JFrame and disabling the JFrame until the dialog closes, then handling the clicks from the dialog when the dialog closes.

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

    Window window;
    JFrame jFrame;
    JDialog jDialog;
    String whichButton;

    public Frame() {
        this.jDialog = initDialog();
        this.jFrame = initFrame();
    }

    private JFrame initFrame() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        JButton b = new JButton("Click Me!!");
        b.requestFocusInWindow();
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Button b clicked");
                setWhichButton("");
                getjFrame().setEnabled(false);
                getjDialog().setVisible(true);
                getjDialog().requestFocusInWindow();
                // the FocusListener will handle input from dialog
            }
        });
        add(b);

        try {
            JDialog jd = getjDialog();
            add(jd);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // swallow for now
        }

        setWindow(this);

        return this;

    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        String selectedButton = getWhichButton();
        switch (selectedButton) {
            case "b1":
                System.out.println("Button b1 was clicked");
                break;
            case "b2":
                System.out.println("Button b2 was clicked");
                break;
            case "b3":
                System.out.println("Button b3 was clicked");
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }

// The Panel to add dynamically

    private JDialog initDialog() {
        JDialog jd = new JDialog();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        jd.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jd.setFocusable(true);
        jd.setSize(300, 300);
        jd.setVisible(false);
        jd.setLocation(100, 50);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("option 1");
        b1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Button b1 clicked");
                setWhichButton("b1");
                getjDialog().setVisible(false);
                getjFrame().setEnabled(true);
                getjFrame().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        JButton b2 = new JButton("option 2");
        b2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Button b2 clicked");
                setWhichButton("b2");
                getjDialog().setVisible(false);
                getjFrame().setEnabled(true);
                getjFrame().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        JButton b3 = new JButton("option 3");
        b3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Button b3 clicked");
                setWhichButton("b3");
                getjDialog().setVisible(false);
                getjFrame().setEnabled(true);
                getjFrame().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        jd.add(b1);
        jd.add(b2);
        jd.add(b3);

        jd.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                getjFrame().setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        return jd;
    }

    public Window getWindow() {
        return window;
    }

    private void setWindow(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public JDialog getjDialog() {
        return jDialog;
    }

    public void setjDialog(JDialog jDialog) {
        this.jDialog = jDialog;
    }

    public JFrame getjFrame() {
        return jFrame;
    }

    public void setjFrame(JFrame jFrame) {
        this.jFrame = jFrame;
    }

    public String getWhichButton() {
        return whichButton;
    }

    public void setWhichButton(String whichButton) {
        this.whichButton = whichButton;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was looking for adding a jPanel after clicking the button, not a jDialog.

Comment: Do you want the b1/b2/b3 component to remain after selecting a button?

Comment: No, The JPanel that will contain the buttons b1, b2 & b3 should disappear after making the selection...

Comment: It will work, but I think it will not look good. I want to do that only as a last resort. I think it looks better if there is a JPanel added rather than popping a dialog box...

Comment: Would you please attach a mock-up of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the member function .setDisabled() to disable b, then use .setEnabled() to reenable it. You can easily disable b when it is pressed, and reenable it with an action listener when b1, b2, or b3 is pressed.

Comment: Ok, that will prevent further button presses. But I want the rest of the button b's event handling code (from the point where I display the JPanel) to pause as well until a choice is made between b1,b2 & b3.

Comment: please see the 3rd paragraph, I edited my question.

Comment: In that case you can spin in a while() loop until a choice is made; move the part of b's logic that you want to wait into a separate event handler listening for a press of b1, b2, or b3; or use a separate thread to control b's logic and have that thread sleep() until a choice is made.

Comment: Can you please share a small example of using a separate thread to do this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `setDisabled()` is a JavaFX method and this question is tagged as _swing_. What am I missing?

Comment: @Abra That is why I did not accept this answer yet. setDisabled() is not a valid solution.

Comment: @Abra Sorry guys, had my syntax a little wrong. setDisabled() is not a Swing function, but setEnabled() is, and it takes a boolean: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Comment: @jCoder Sorry for the late reply. You can use SwingWorkers to add multithreading to your Swing applications pretty easily. Multithreading is a must if you want your button's on pressed logic to hang for any length of time, in order to keep the Event Dispatch Thread, on which all Swing GUI events run, from freezing. I will say though that I think it would be better to just add another action listener for when the user selects b1, b2, or b3. Oracle has a great tutorial on multithreading in Swing if that's the route you go: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html